# WCF unrecognized message version

Tags: .net, wcf, exception

I'm facing a problem with my console application that tries to send data via a WCF service. I did manage to send another type of data via another WCF service that uses same configuration in my other console app. 
For configuration I used in both console apps :

```
var binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly;
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;
binding.Security.Transport.ProxyCredentialType = HttpProxyCredentialType.Basic;
binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647;
var endpoint =new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress("the end point");

var theClient = new MyClient(binding,endpoint);
theClient .ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "Username";
theClient .ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "Password";
```

After this configuration I used the method for sending my data. I also tried to send the data xml -that I gathered from fiddler- via Postman Chrome extension. I was able to send the xml via Postman but not in the console app. I think there is a problem with my configuration. Stacktrace :

```
Unrecognized message version. 
Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReceivedMessage.ReadStartEnvelope(XmlDictionaryReader reader)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedMessage..ctor(IBufferedMessageData messageData, RecycledMessageState recycledMessageState, Boolean[] understoodHeaders, Boolean understoodHeadersModified)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TextMessageEncoderFactory.TextMessageEncoder.ReadMessage(ArraySegment`1 buffer, BufferManager bufferManager, String contentType)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.DecodeBufferedMessage(ArraySegment`1 buffer, Stream inputStream)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ReadBufferedMessage(Stream inputStream)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ParseIncomingMessage(HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage, Exception& requestException)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Integrator.WCFSer.Z_BAPI_SLS_ORD_CREATE_WITH_DEL.ZBapiSlsOrdCreateWithDel(ZBapiSlsOrdCreateWithDelRequest request)
   at Integrator.WCFSer.Z_BAPI_SLS_ORD_CREATE_WITH_DELClient.Integrator.WCFSer.Z_BAPI_SLS_ORD_CREATE_WITH_DEL.ZBapiSlsOrdCreateWithDel(ZBapiSlsOrdCreateWithDelRequest request)
   at Integrator.WCFSer.Z_BAPI_SLS_ORD_CREATE_WITH_DELClient.ZBapiSlsOrdCreateWithDel(ZBapiSlsOrdCreateWithDel ZBapiSlsOrdCreateWithDel1)
   at Integrator.Program.Main(String[] args) mscorlibz\Integrator\Program.cs:line 113 mscorlib
```

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to check your Endpoint Address especially when you are working with **wsdl files**. For that you can follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72977645/10278470)

In the case you want to specify a specific **Soap Version** you have to modify your binding to a **custom binding** as follows:

```csharp
var binding = new CustomBinding();

//custom text message and encoding binding configs
TextMessageEncodingBindingElement textBindingElement = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement
{
    //specify your custom Soap message version below, in this case (Soap 1.1)
    MessageVersion = MessageVersion.CreateVersion(EnvelopeVersion.Soap11, 
    AddressingVersion.WSAddressing10), 
    WriteEncoding = Encoding.UTF8,
    ReaderQuotas = System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max,

};

//custom transport binding including authentication configs
HttpTransportBindingElement httpBindingElement = new HttpTransportBindingElement
{
    AllowCookies = false,
    MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue,
    MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue,
    TransferMode = TransferMode.Buffered,
    UseDefaultWebProxy = false,
    ProxyAuthenticationScheme = AuthenticationSchemes.Basic,
    AuthenticationScheme = AuthenticationSchemes.Basic,

};

binding.Elements.Add(textBindingElement);
binding.Elements.Add(httpBindingElement);

var endpoint = new EndpointAddress("the end point");
var client = new MyClient(binding,endpoint);
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "Username";
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "Password";
```