# How to fix 'Unrecognized Message Version' after changing endpoint address

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-core

I'm trying to consume a WCF service with a new endpoint in .NET Core 3.0.  I added the service reference and have made a successful call.

After changing my WCF endpoint address to the same address I originally used, I'm getting an 'Unrecognized message version.' error.  How can I get past this error?

I've already tried using a custom binding, changing the transport type, and SOAP version.  I've narrowed down the issue to the endpoint address.

With the below snippet's commented line included, I get the error message.  When I keep the address commented out, the service returns a valid response.  I've verified that the service uses basic HTTP binding with no credentials needed.

```cs
using var client = new AccountServiceClient();
// client.Endpoint.Address = new EndpointAddress("<url redacted>");
var response = client.getAccountAsync(new AccountRequest ...
```

I am using the same URL in code as the one I originally configured for testing purposes; however, this URL will change depending on environment.  The expected result should populate the response variable.  Instead, I'm getting the following error message:

```
System.AggregateException : One or more errors occurred. (Unrecognized message version.)
---- System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException : Unrecognized message version.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved my issue by removing the "?wsdl" from the URL of the service in the endpoint address.

For example, if the URL was "http://server/service?wsdl", I entered "http://server/service" in the endpoint address.

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue working with a `SAP wsdl` file. Unlike this [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58825875/10278470) my link did not have the `?wsdl`. In my case i noticed i was using the **wsdl url** instead of the **wsdl endpoint**

> My `wsdl url` is like: http://192.168.0.11:8088/sap/bc/srt/wsdl/bndg_WBTSRN34RT681000000C0A8010A/wsdl11/allinone/ws_policy/document?sap-client=200

All i needed was to use the **wsdl endpoint** insted of the **wsdl url**.
To find the **wsdl endpoint** open the **wsdl file** and check the `address location` under the `wsdl:service` tag

```xml
  <wsdl:service name="ZWS_FILEService">
    <wsdl:port name="ZWS_FILE" binding="tns:ZWS_FILE">
      <soap:address location="http://192.168.0.11:8088/sap/bc/srt/rfc/sap/zws_file/200/zws_file/zws_file"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
```

Comment: Hi, I'm facing the same issue. I cannot find the tag <wsdl:service> in my wsdl. Do you know how to get it?